# DateTime: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php, date, datetime, syntax-error

It works fine on `localhost`, but when I upload it to my host online it shows this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR
```

How can I fix it? Do I have to define the `DateTime` function somewhere?

```
if ((new DateTime($date))->diff(new DateTime())->days > 10) { 
    echo 'test';
}
```

UPDATE:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-M-d l H:i a', $date);
if ($date->diff(new DateTime())->days > 10) {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class member access on instantiation was added in PHP 5.4. You are probably running PHP 5.3 so you cannot use that syntax.

Change:

```
if ((new DateTime($date))->diff(new DateTime())->days > 10) {
```

to:

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
if ($date->diff(new DateTime())->days > 10) {
```

Comment: it seemed to fix somewhat, at least the page works again but now i get this in the content: " Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (14-Feb-11 Tuesday 13:14 pm) at position 24 (p): The timezone could not be found in the database' in"

Comment: That is not a valid format to pass to DateTime. You will need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse that format and create a valid datetime object.

Comment: i am using TIMESTAMP as type for my `date` field if that makes a difference

Comment: how do you do that? i have never really played with datetime before

Comment: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-M-d l H:i a', $date);`

Comment: now im getting a shorted error that says "Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat()". i updated my code above so you see what i have currently

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: for now im using 000webhost.com (for testing) and it's 5.2.x. i used godaddy but i canceled them as no point paying while testing

Comment: They must be running an old version of PHP. This really limits your options. I would recommend using xampp or wamp for testing. At least that way you can use a modern version of PHP. Anyway, you need to convert that date/time into a proper format: YYYY-MM-DD H:i:ss or a unix timestamp then pass it to DateTime. What does that date look likein your database?

Comment: i see what you mean. i guess i have to get a host online that has the newest php! and in my database i see 2014-02-12 16:10:14 everything works fine.. it is the free hosting that causes necessary problems haha